# Возможно ли на regexp perl удалить определенное число байтов из строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl, байты

Есть строка текста в которой в произвольном месте может содержаться "мусорный" текст который нужно вычистить. У "мусора" следующие параметры он оканчивается на \x00\x00 (в hex представлении), а в начале \xE3\x33 но при этом он не всегда находится в самом начале иногда перед ним бывает 1 или 2 символа. При этом длинна "мусорной" строки всегда 70 байт. Встречается "мусор" произвольное число раз.

**Возможно ли на Perl составить такое регулярное выражение или два три выражения которое удаляло бы ненужное?**

Comment: ну собственно от обычного текста никаких отличий нет `s/\xE3\x33.*?\x00\x00//`. Ну или заменить `.*?` на явное `.{70}` правда он точку может интерпретировать как шировкие символы. тут вопрос в наличии флага юникода на входной строке (по хорошему должен отсутствовать) и возможно придется работать под прагмой `use bytes`

Comment: Забыл добавить подобная последовательность (\x00\x00) может быть не один раз внутри "мусора". И начинается не строго с \xE3\x33. В начале бывает еще 1-2 символа произвольных, но длинна всегда 70 байт.

Comment: ну тогда 00 не писать в условие, а использовать явные `.{70}` На счет "_И начинается не строго с \xE3\x33_" ну это компьютер, ему надо  строго формализовать задачу, ищите более точные признаки "мусора"

Comment: лучше наверное показать возможные примеры мусорных строк

Comment: Я понимаю это, но подумал может есть какая то хитрость, отталкиваясь от конца отрезать 70 байт. Правда как тогда конец найти? Он ведь будет от \xE3\x33 68-70 байт.

Comment: А, да, еще после регулярки флаг `s` обязательно задать, забыл.

Comment: Тогда может `.{68,70}\x00\x00` он пропустит 68-70 и поищет там 00

Comment: Вот пример только не знаю чем поможет. Начинается мусор после **":"XX**, а заканчивается 
 **L     5.** ":"XX$.3^.K^L^@P^F^@^@P^F^@^@^@^T"$$. .0.EU^H^@E^@^FBQ.@^@9^Fd...^A.....^@Pȧ..+...p(P^X^@,.H^@^@L     5.

Comment: Тогда может .{68,70}\x00\x00 А откуда он искать начнет, ведь бывают в середине эти символы? Я думал что от \xE3\x33 отложить 68-70 байт, там найти \x00\x00, а потом от них уже ровно 70 байт отрезать. Не выйдет?

Comment: Не знаю перл, надеялся увидеть пример строки и вариантов для составления регулярного выражения, пока из прочитанного в голову приходит нечто такое для шаблона `(?=.{0,2})(?=.*\x00\x00)\xE3\x33.{66,68}`

Comment: @ИванЖуков Так я часть строки написал, конечно перед `.` идет `\xE3\x33` что бы он с них начал

Comment: Спасибо за наводки, попробую завтра сделать, уже не на работе. И отпишусь если подучить я.

Comment: Поступил проще сначала перевернул строку, а потом искал \x00\x00 и от них уже искал 70 байт и вырезал, потом строку обратно переворачивал. Примерно так:`$row = reverse($row);
   $row=~s/\x00\x00.{68}//g;     
   $row = reverse($row);`
И все получилось. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: переворачивание строки создаст новую строку и может съесть память на больших объёмах. лучше уж 70 байт откусить. или пару ретроспективных проверок сделать